# block variable for read

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I have the following code:

```
private DateTime lastUploadActivityTime = DateTime.Now;
private void HttpSendProgress(object sender, HttpProgressEventArgs e)
{
    // update variable
    lastUploadActivityTime = DateTime.Now;
    ......
    boolThreadAvailableTargetSiteActive = false;
}

// this method is executed in different thread, than method above
private void ThreadCheckAvailableTargetSite()
{
    while (boolThreadAvailableTargetSiteActive)
    {
        if (lastUploadActivityTime.AddSeconds(5) <= DateTime.Now)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("BREAK");
            boolThreadAvailableTargetSiteActive = false;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

I need to block the variable lastUploadActivityTime in first method (during `lastUploadActivityTime = DateTime.Now;`) to prevent read lastUploadActivityTime in second method (`lastUploadActivityTime.AddSeconds(5) <= DateTime.Now`). How can I do it? Does `Mutex` help me to prevent reading variable?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lock` keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released. Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances.

```
private object syncLock = new object();
private DateTime lastUploadActivityTime = DateTime.Now;
private void HttpSendProgress(object sender, HttpProgressEventArgs e)
{
    // update variable
    lock (syncLock)
    {
       lastUploadActivityTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

// this method is executed in different thread, than method above
private void ThreadCheckAvailableTargetSite()
{
    while (boolThreadAvailableTargetSiteActive)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
           if (lastUploadActivityTime.AddSeconds(5) <= DateTime.Now)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("BREAK");
               boolThreadAvailableTargetSiteActive = false;
           }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: lock variable should be reference type :)

Comment: The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.

Comment: Please clarify that _variables_ are not locked, but rather code regions, and that it's necessary to identify all code regions which could read the variable, and lock them, hence the value of using properties for access to such variables.

Comment: also, should I declare boolThreadAvailableTargetSiteActive as private volatile bool boolThreadAvailableTargetSiteActive = true; ?

Answer (score 1):

mutex would be overkill, use lock instead in both methods to syncronize read
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx